# How do I setup Nestjs to host a React site?

Tags: reactjs, nestjs

All the examples I've seen are with React running in one server and Nestjs running on another.  I know Nestjs can host a site, but how do I set it up to host a React site?

Comment: @ZEE please explain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use NestJS serve static module to serve up the react application that you built

See
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static
and
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: Thank you Ray!  That helps a lot.  Do you know if there is an example of using the static module with web sockets?

Comment: Hi @Heath I do not see any documentation for that. If I get some time over the weekend I will try dig a little deeper to see if they have any.

Comment: Is there any example that I can refer to so that I can get the configuration exactly correct?